# Python printing the contents of a text file whenever the user wants to

Tags: python

I am currently partaking in my A Level computer science programming project I am making a program in python that takes the user's type of colour-blindness and what colour they see, then shows them the correct colour based of the type of colour-blindness. For example;

> What's your type of colour-Blindness?
>
> ->Red-Green
>
> What colour do you see?
>
> ->Red
>
> The actual colour is;
>
> ->Green *shows the colour green*

However there is more than one type of color-blindness and there is quite a lot of information needed to know the difference between so I thought I the best way to represent this would be on a separate text file that could be called upon at will. If there is not a viable way then I was going to have the data stored in a variable inside a while loop and when the keyword "info" would be typed in the program would just dump all the info

Thank you to anyone who answers me it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Or your research.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh I have not really tried anything of note yet because my level of understanding of writing/reading to/from a file is minuscule. I know I have to open and close the file but using the file between those two points is beyond me. I have not completed typing up my research yet but it is roughly the size of two 10 sentence paragraphs. If my research is explicitly needed then I can try and finish it, but I am unable to do it until Monday.